# Windows Server 2008, can't ping, but networking is fine

Tags: windows-server-2008, ping

I'm setting up a Windows Server 2008 box, and everything is working great (database, remote login, etc.), but it doesn't respond to ping.  Normally I might not care, but I'm setting up Nagios monitoring for it, too, and Nagios seems to want to know it can ping it.

My first thought was the firewall, but I even tried turning the firewall off entirely for a minute, and I still couldn't ping it.

What am I missing?  Is there something I need to enable/disable to make ping work?

(Have pity ... I'm normally a Unix admin, not a Windows admin.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I'm an idiot.  I'd tried turning the firewall off but only managed to do so for one profile.  The public profile (duh) was indeed blocking ICMP ECHO.

Solved...

Comment: You didn't turn off the public profile firewall, did you?  I'm pretty sure you would have just enabled ICMP Echo but your wording has me worried!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..what I did to my Win Server 2008 R2 Ent.. was click to Administrative Tools then Windows Firewall and Advanced Security..go to Inbound Rules..navigate to File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMv4-in) as well as ICMv6in) and voila i can ping now..

Marlon V. Macua
LGU-Trinidad, Bohol
Sys Admin